# Beautifulsoup and amending a list

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am getting to know my first programming language and I am having a bit of a problem trying out an exercise that uses BS4 and Python.

The pages that I am attempting to scrape are located below in the following link:
https://www.aisc.org/certification/certified-company-search2/certified-company-search/?companyName=&country=select&city=&state=&canState=&zipCode=&radius=&certification=&certs=&pageSize=10&sort=aCompany

If you click on any of the links generated from the list the url for the specific company becomes:
https://www.aisc.org/certification/certified-company?id=3220678

What I am attempting to do is scrape the data, which is not in table form and convert it to an excel csv file with the company name, and then each line about the company information in its' own column (ie. address, telephone, email, etc).  I have managed to separate the company name and company information, but I am having trouble adding the company name to the list.  I am also having trouble parsing the tags from the company information.  If I use row+= line.text, then the output is row = ['a','d', 'd','r','e',.......]

Any help would be appreciated and below you will find the input and output from my code.

Thanks,

```
INPUT:
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


page = requests.get("https://www.aisc.org/certification/certified-company?id=3220678")
print(page.status_code)
print(page.content)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')
#print(soup.prettify())
#print(soup.find_all('ul', class_='vlist project-details-list'))
#print(soup.find_all('div', class_='unit size1of1'))

for header in soup.find_all('div', class_='unit size1of1'):
    for company in header.find_all('h1'):
        print(company.text)
for line in soup.find_all('ul', class_='vlist project-details-list'):
    row = []
    row+= line
print(row)



OUTPUT:
2-K Steel Products, Inc.
['\n', <li><strong>Address:</strong> 65 Murray Circle</li>, '\n', <li><strong>City:</strong> Ashville</li>, '\n', <li><strong>State:</strong> AL</li>, '\n', <li><strong>Zip Code:</strong>     35953</li>, '\n', <li><strong>Country:</strong> United States</li>, '\n', <li><strong>Contact:</strong> Mr. Kal Kimbrough </li>, '\n', <li><strong>Email Address:</strong> <a href="mailto:kkimbrough@2ksteel.com">kkimbrough@2ksteel.com</a></li>, '\n', <li><strong>Phone:</strong> (205) 594-5446</li>, '\n', <li><strong>Website:</strong> <a alt="2-K Steel Products, Inc." href="http://www.2ksteel.com" target="_blank">www.2ksteel.com</a></li>, '\n', <li><strong>Certification/Endorsement Types:</strong> BU</li>, '\n']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two main problems with the `for` loop you're asking about.

1. Each time it loops, it re-initializes `row` to `[]`, the empty list.
2. You're using `+=` to append to a list, which doesn't do what you seem to expect it to.

Instead, you need to move the initialization before the loop, and use `append()`:

```
row = []
for line in soup.find_all('ul', class_='vlist project-details-list'):
    row.append(line)
```

When you use `+=` with a list on the left, it expects the right to be a *sequence*.  It just so happens that strings are a type of sequence, specifically of characters.  That's what you're seeing when you run your code: you're `extend`ing the list with the values in the sequence.